# Decrement field for all users in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database and I'm running a php script daily. I was wondering how to decrement all records in the database for a specific field until they get to zero and then stop.

I was thinking to decrement them I would use

```
UPDATE table set field = field - 1
```

Is this correct? If it is correct how would I make sure that field never drops below zero? Thanks

Comment: In MySQL, you can use an `update` trigger.

Comment: SQL triggers happen after an insert, delete or select has occurred. I want it to happen once every day at midnight

Comment: This is unclear.  If you want the field to just become zero for all records, can't you do `UPDATE table SET field = 0;`?  Alternatively, if you are saying that you want to decrement the value by one each day, until it becomes zero, why don't you do `UPDATE table SET field = field-1 WHERE field > 0;`?  Or, you can have `UPDATE table SET field = MAX(0, field-1);` if you want to scan all rows every day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add simple where clause update only rows where field  is greater than 0

```
UPDATE table 
SET field = field - 1
WHERE field  > 0
```

Comment: Will this statement then update all rows for that specific field?

Comment: @KVohra95 this statement will update all rows where your field has a greater value than 0 , rows with value 0 will not be affected

Comment: Also if the field is intented to have always non negative values consider to make it unsigned.